# How to make input on autofocus for IE browsers?

Tags: html, css, input

I want to be able to make my input on autofocus but when I put it like this:

```
<input type="text" autofocus="focus">
```

it doesnt work?

Why is this?

Answer (score 12):

`autofocus` attribute isn't supported by IE, so you need to use Javascript. If you use jquery, you can emulate it:

```
<input type="text" autofocus="focus"> 
<script>
    $(function() {$('[autofocus]').focus()});
</script>
```

When IE catches up and adds full `autofocus` support, you can remove the script from your webpage.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JavaScript, it will solve your problem:
copy this to your HTML body open tag:

`<body OnLoad="document.nameOfForm.nameOfField.focus();">`

Comment: certainly simpler than my version, go for this one

Comment: missing closing quote `"` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to do it.

You should set focus on document.ready with jquery.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/m77QP/

Comment: or just use a setTimeout and wait a second, exactly a second

Answer (score 0):

`document.getELementById("inputidtag").focus`

use that in a script area within the document (`body` or `head`) and it will run at startup, you may want to put it at the end of the document (or at least after the object) so that when it runs, it will find it, not throw an error about how it can't be found.that will set the element with the id `inputidtag` to focus.